# Faster way to get range from 2-dimensional array, than assigning elements one by one to another array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, range

For example I have some array: `byte[,] arr = new byte[4800, 3000];` and I need to get part of that array starting from 512, 600 and ending at 1024, 1200.

How I can do that fast?

All I can think of is this:

```
int start_x = 512, start_y = 600;
int end_x = 1024, end_y = 1200;

byte[,] new_arr = byte[end_x - start_x, end_y - start_y];

for (int x = start_x; x < end_x; x++)
    for (int y = start_y; y < end_y; y++)
        new_arr[x - start_x, y - start_y] = arr[x, y];
```

but that's a lot of assign operations. Is there any faster way?

Comment: Have you tried `Buffer.BlockCopy`? That would be my first port of call. (It would only remove one level of looping, admittedly.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I didn't even knew it exists :) Will try now how it works...

Comment: @JonSkeet - That's interesting thing. Still Interesting if there is some more fast way exists, since I may need to copy nearly all elements minus 1 - 2 lines.

Comment: Well, it's slightly odd that you're using the `x` value as the "primary" value here to start with (i.e. columns rather than rows)... but if you're copying a single contiguous chunk of memory, then you could use a single `Buffer.BlockCopy` call.

Comment: I'd also strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Make it as answer, so I can accept it when time comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy a block of contiguous memory from one array to another. For example:

```
// Names changed to be more conventional
int originalHeight = ...; // Original "height" in array
int newHeight = endY - startY;
for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++)
{        
    Buffer.BlockCopy(
        array, x * height + startY, // Copying from here...
        newArray, x * newHeight,    // To here...
        newHeight);                 // A whole column
}
```

If you're copying *complete* columns (i.e. `startY` is 0, and `endY` is `originalHeight`) then you could just call `Buffer.BlockCopy` once, with the appropriate values.

If you're really thinking about copying *lines* rather than columns, you might want to consider reordering your arrays so that the `y` value comes first - currently you have the whole of the first column, followed by the whole of the second column etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a **little bit** more efficient by removing un-necessary re-calculation of `x - start_x`:

```
int start_x = 512, start_y = 600;
int end_x = 1024, end_y = 1200;

byte[,] new_arr = byte[end_x - start_x, end_y - start_y];

for (int x = start_x; x < end_x; x++)
{
    int target_x = x - start_x;

    for (int y = start_y; y < end_y; y++)
        new_arr[target_x, y - start_y] = arr[x, y];
}
```

Comment: Right, sometimes things like that can happen :P